# Static page on Ghost blog is broken

Tags: html, css, ghost-blog

My site http://willemwijnans.github.com is showing a bug. For some reason the static pages do not work anymore. From the Menu there are 3 options:

- About
- Services
- Contact

If I press about, a download bar pops up. It used to show my about.html page, which is a static page in my ghost editor.
If I press services, it for some reason links to my local instance of the ghost blog (where I create it from)
Contact can be ignored, I did not build that yet.

My code is in my github repository, which can be found here: https://github.com/WillemWijnans/willemwijnans.github.io

Am I overlooking something really obvious? Thanks.

I think its something wrong in the default.hbs page, since this page is rendered from there:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
{{! Document Settings }}
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

{{! Page Meta }}
<title>{{meta_title}}</title>
<meta name="description" content="{{meta_description}}" />

<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True" />
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

{{! Link to your favicon }}
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/images/favicon.ico" />

{{! Styles'n'Scripts }}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/screen.css" />

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,300italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700|Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800|Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">

{{! Ghost outputs important style and meta data with this tag }}
{{ghost_head}}

<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-56927501-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
 </script>
    </head>
<body class="{{body_class}}">

{{! Everything else gets inserted here }}
{{{body}}}

<footer class="site-footer">

    <a class="go-top" href="#top" title="Back to Top">
        <span><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up fa-4x"></i></span>
    </a>

    <div class="inner">
        <section class="poweredby"><a href="{{@blog.url}}">{{@blog.title}}</a>  &copy; All Rights Reserved, 2014 
        </section>
    </div>
</footer>

{{! Ghost outputs important scripts and data with this tag }}
{{ghost_foot}}


{{! The main JavaScript file for Phantom }}
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/icons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
```

This is the page.hbs file:

```
 {{!< default}}

{{! The comment above "< default" means - insert everything in this file into
the {body} of the default.hbs template, which contains our header/footer. }}

{{! The main content area on the homepage }}
<main class="content" role="main">

<!-- Page Sidebar -->
    {{! The tag below includes the page sidebar - partials/page-sidebar.hbs }}

    {{> "page-sidebar"}}


<!-- Page Content -->

{{! Each post will be output using this markup }}

<div class='post-holder'>    

    {{! Everything inside the #post tags pulls data from the post }}

    <article class="{{post_class}}">  
    {{#post}}

        <h1 class="page-title">{{{title}}}</h1>

        <section class="post-content">
            {{content}}
        </section>

        {{/post}}

    </article>   

</div>
```

Fixed it, the CSS selector was not right

Comment: Expecting us to trail around the Internet looking for your code is not the way to ask a question. See [ask]

Comment: i think your services static page `<a href="http://127.0.0.1:2368/services"><span><i class="fa fa-gear"></i></span> Services</a>` looks like this. i feel `.html is missing after127.0.0.1:2368/services`

Comment: I see the about us page. The first sentence "I am Willem Wijnans and I like to talk nerdy about 'recruitment'". I am on Chrome 38.0.2125.111. The service page says coming soon.

Comment: I fixed it by going manually through the code. In the end the sidebar was not rightly configured. @ Hobo thanks for sharing the how to ask a questions. And thank you Manjunath & Andrew for replying: Case closed